# unable to use pagination rules in Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to use the Pagination rules in the ADF rest source to download all my pages data. My API looks something like this: www.xyz.com?page=0 and i get the response like this : 
{content:[],

totalPages:"150",

page:0}
Here is the pagination rule that i am trying to write to fetch the next page data

QueryParameters.page = @add(int($.page),1) but this is reflecting an error saying UnsupportedConcept and showing invalid.

Please tell if there is any way to increment the value of a response and hit the api again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an until loop.

Create a pipeline that contains a variable that will be evaluated by the until activity and a call to your api to get the total number of pages (or the 1st batch of data). 
Then, inside the Until activity, you run it until your @equals(pipeline.variable, activity('1stcall').output.totalPages).

The activities inside the until should be a 
-Another web call to your appy
-A set variable activity increasing the value of the page variable.

Comment: Thanks @JLuis It worked. I didn't know there was some web activity available. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @JLuisEstrada, Here is what I have done :
web Activity -> setTotalPage Variable ->until Activity 
There is a limitation with the web activity that the response should not exceed 1Mb, but the response I receive is around 700Mb. So the pipeline is getting failed. Is there any way or substitution for web activity just to hit the API and capture total page info from it. I had implemented this solution using Azure functions but in our requirement, we don't have to use that. 
Please let me know if you have some innovative ideas regarding this. It will be of great help.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response. Does the Copy Activity with a REST API Source doesnt work for you? see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest